# Is there a way to store message box settings to be used repetitively in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to use the same message box repetitively in a Powershell script, without having to reiterate all the settings each time.  I initially thought that I would store it as a variable:

```
$StandardMessage = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Repetitive Message.", "Chores.")
```

But as I found out this simply stores the user's response to the message box in the variable.

What I would like to do is something similar to the following pseudo-code:

```
$StandardMessage = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Repetitive Message.", "Chores.")

While(true){

    If(condition){
        $StandardMessage
    }
    If(condition2){
        $StandardMessage
    }

}
```

Where the conditions would be time-based.  This is essentially displaying a message at specified times during the day.

Asked another way (and perhaps more clearly): Is it possible to 'define' a messagebox without actually 'showing' it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Function my good man!

```
Function Show-MyMessage{
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Repetitive Message.", "Chores.")
}

While(true){

    If(condition){
        Show-MyMessage
    }
    If(condition2){
        Show-MyMessage
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Personally I have this function on hand for several of my scripts to use as needed:

```
Function Show-MsgBox ($Text,$Title="",[Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]$Button = "OK"){
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Text", "$Title", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::$Button, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information) | ?{(!($_ -eq "OK"))}
}
```

Then I can just call it as needed, like:

```
Show-MsgBox -Title "You want the truth?" -Text "You can't handle the truth!"
```

And I've got a pop up with the text and title I want, and an OK button.

[image]

Buttons can be specified (there's a pop-up for it in the ISE to give options), and title can be excluded if I am feeling lazy. Only thing I really have to feed it is the message.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.  I was too focused on finding an in-line solution (such as theoretically replacing ::show with ::define or something along those lines) to think about using a function.  Out of curiosity, does anyone know of a way to do this without a function?